# Can I generate a URL pointing at a group of routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I can define a group of named Laravel routes like this:

```php
Route::prefix('things')->as('things.')->group(
    static function () {
        Route::get('thing1', [ThingController::class, 'thing1'])
            ->name('thing1');
        Route::get('thing2', [ThingController::class, 'thing2'])
            ->name('thing2');
    }
);
```

and this will define named routes of `things.thing1` and `things.thing2`, with corresponding URLs of `/things/thing1` and `/things/thing2`.

From this little route collection I want to extract the nominal "base" URL for the group itself, i.e. just `/things`, by calling `route('things')` (or similar), even though there is no single named route that corresponds to that exactly, and there is no controller to handle it. Is that possible?

The reason I need to do this is that this base URL needs to be passed to an external API, which is responsible for adding on the handler names (`thing1` & `thing2`). I know I could simply define this URL separately in some literal, however, that doesn't seem very DRY, when the information is right there in the route prefix definition.

To clarify, the URLs are split into two parts:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/something/things/thing1
|--------------base-----------------|---routes---|
```

The routes are only concerned about what happens in the routes part of this, but the `/v1/something` part needs to be extracted from this set to be provided to the external API which builds its own set of routes starting from the same point. So I provide `https://api.example.com/v1/something` as a base URL to the external API, and that API then calls `/things/thing1` etc within that namespace.

I guess the question is really, if I define a route prefix like this:

```
Route::prefix('things')...
```

Can I later extract that prefix from the route list, or do I have to repeat the definition?

Comment: Seems confusing you are talking about DRY yourself when the route structure in itself is very repetitive. Isn't there a way to create with a a single controller function and route with an url parameter?

Comment: Route::get('/', [ThingController::class, 'index']) or maybe i did not understand question. And thing1/2 look like route param, not separate routes

Comment: No, no, thing1 and thing2 are not intended to be route params, they are different operations. Perhaps I should have named them function1 and function2 or something to illustrate; also it doesn't matter what they are called because it's the route group I want to target not the endpoints, but a key thing is that there is no index so there is no `/` route in the group – though I could conceivably add one (that does nothing) just as a means of naming the group, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: If you choose ro use REST the operation is defined by the verb not by the uri:). use things/{function} when defining the route and depending on the function value call the specific function. if not found return 404 (if you don't want to use REST)

Comment: This is still missing the point - it's not my design (it's actually Apple's Wallet API). I just want to know if, having defined a group of routes, if I can extract a partial URL that points at that group of routes itself. It makes *absolutely no difference* what the actual routes within the group are (i.e. REST status is irrelevant), so please ignore them. I know that this will not be a usable route itself, but it will give me the partial URL - think of it like an "abstract route".